# In Jmeter 3.2 latest version "Replace All" feature not working

Tags: jmeter

I have installed latest Jmeter 3.2 version. When I tried to use "Replace All" feature it's not working.It's searching properly but replace all not working. See the below screenshots.

I expected "PensionReport" replace with "PR"

Please advise!

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: I just tried. Try clicking on Search, Search and Expand, and then click on Replace All. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It works fine. Not able to reproduce your issue. But there is a bug in the Search Tree functionality. I have raised a defect in Bugzilla. Here is the link: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61011

Comment: @Naveen, I just tried,no it's not working

Comment: Use regular expression. `(.+?)PensionReport(.+?)` in search and in replace `(.+?)PR(.+?)`

Comment: No.Even it's not  even able to search.I don't think search and replace all should be that much complex!

Comment: My bad. I have raised a defect with JMeter. Here is the link https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61016. There should be quick fix to it.

Comment: @Naveen, I have already raised. Here is the link https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61015

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142205/discussion-between-naveenkumar-namachivayam-and-rpagadala).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReplaceAll does not do replacement on all elements as per release notes:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

> A replace feature has been added to Search feature to allow replacement in some elements.

So feature does replacement on following parts:

- [HeaderManager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager):

  - Replacement in values
- [Http Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request):

  - Replacement in Arguments
  - Replacement in Path
  - Replacement in Host

This feature will evolve in the future but it has been limited to most useful replacements that are required for correlation.

Note there was a bug in counting that has been fixed in nightly build:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61011

Read this blog for more details on 3.2:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/apache-jmeter-major-version-3-2-released-enjoy-the-new-features/